# custom bottomNavigationBar help need in flutter to call pages into view

Tags: flutter, custom-view, bottom-navigation-bar

I have a working page of code that I wanted to modify for my portfolio. I used this YouTube https://youtu.be/1ToqYMSnNhA and git https://github.com/retroportalstudio/flutter_bnb_v2 to make my design, but now I can't get my pages to call in.

working Code I used...

```
circular_bottom_navigation: ^2.3.0
```

```
class MainScreenScaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreenScaffold({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainScreenScaffold> createState() => _MainScreenScaffoldState();
}

bool value = false;

class _MainScreenScaffoldState extends State<MainScreenScaffold> {
  late List<Map<String, Object>> _pages;
  int _selectedPageIndex = 2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pages = [
      {
        'page': Abilities(),
      },
      {
        'page': Education(),
      },
      {
        'page': HomePage(),
      },
      {
        'page': Employment(),
      },
      {
        'page': About(),
      },
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  void _selectPage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedPageIndex = index;
    });
  }

  bool _onTap = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeState = Provider.of<DarkThemeProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 40,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark ? navigationBarsDMColor : navigationBarsLMColor,
        elevation: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark ? 0.0 : 3.0,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: FaIcon(
                themeState.darkTheme
                    ? FontAwesomeIcons.lightbulb
                    : FontAwesomeIcons.lightbulb,
                size: 20,
                color: _onTap ? Colors.black : Colors.white),
            tooltip: 'Light/Dark Mode',
            onPressed: () {
              themeState.darkTheme = value;
              setState(() {
                value = !value;
                _onTap = !_onTap;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (context) => IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
            },
            icon: FaIcon(
                themeState.darkTheme
                    ? FontAwesomeIcons.bars
                    : FontAwesomeIcons.bars,
                size: 20,
                color: _onTap ? Colors.black : Colors.white),
            tooltip: 'Quick Look',
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: AnimatedCapsuleButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Open the webpage here
          },
          darkModeColor: yellowDMColor,
          lightModeColor: yellowLMColor,
          text: 'Resume',
        ),
      ),

      drawer: SkillsPageDrawer(),
      body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'] as Widget,

      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        notchMargin: 0.1,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        child: Container(
          height: kBottomNavigationBarHeight * 1.1,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [

                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark ? orangeDMColor : orangeLMColor,
                  ),
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.bar_chart, color: Colors.white),
                    onPressed: () => _selectPage(0),
                    tooltip: 'Abilities',
                  ),
                ),

                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark ? greenDMColor : greenLMColor,
                  ),
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.school, color: Colors.white),
                    onPressed: () => _selectPage(1),
                    tooltip: 'Education',
                  ),
                ),

                SizedBox(width: 48), // This empty space is for the FAB.

                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark ? purpleDMColor : purpleLMColor,
                  ),
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.work, color: Colors.white),
                    onPressed: () => _selectPage(3),
                    tooltip: 'Employments',
                  ),
                ),

                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark ? magentaDMColor : magentaLMColor,
                  ),
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white),
                    onPressed: () => _selectPage(4),
                    tooltip: 'About',
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),

      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.miniCenterDocked,
      floatingActionButton: Container(
        height: 70.0,
        width: 70.0,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark ? blueDMColor : blueLMColor,
            foregroundColor: Colors.black,
            hoverElevation: 10,
            splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            tooltip: 'Home',
            elevation: 4,
            child: FaIcon(
                themeState.darkTheme
                    ? FontAwesomeIcons.houseChimney
                    : FontAwesomeIcons.houseChimney,
                color: _onTap ? Colors.white : Colors.white),
            onPressed: () => setState(() {
              _selectedPageIndex = 2;
            }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CypSE.png) working screen shot

not working

```
class MainScreenScaffold3 extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreenScaffold3({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainScreenScaffold3> createState() => _MainScreenScaffold3State();
}

bool value = false;

class _MainScreenScaffold3State extends State<MainScreenScaffold3> {
  late List<Map<String, Object>> _pages;
  int _selectedPageIndex = 2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pages = [
      {
        'page': Abilities(),
      },
      {
        'page': Education(),
      },
      {
        'page': HomePage(),
      },
      {
        'page': Employment(),
      },
      {
        'page': About(),
      },
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  void _selectPage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedPageIndex = index;
    });
  }

  bool _onTap = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeState = Provider.of<DarkThemeProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 40,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark
            ? navigationBarsDMColor
            : navigationBarsLMColor,
        elevation: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark ? 0.0 : 3.0,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: FaIcon(
                themeState.darkTheme
                    ? FontAwesomeIcons.lightbulb
                    : FontAwesomeIcons.lightbulb,
                size: 20,
                color: _onTap ? Colors.black : Colors.white),
            tooltip: 'Light/Dark Mode',
            onPressed: () {
              themeState.darkTheme = value;
              setState(() {
                value = !value;
                _onTap = !_onTap;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (context) => IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
            },
            icon: FaIcon(
                themeState.darkTheme
                    ? FontAwesomeIcons.bars
                    : FontAwesomeIcons.bars,
                size: 20,
                color: _onTap ? Colors.black : Colors.white),
            tooltip: 'Quick Look',
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: AnimatedCapsuleButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Open the webpage here
          },
          darkModeColor: yellowDMColor,
          lightModeColor: yellowLMColor,
          text: 'Resume',
        ),
      ),
      drawer: SkillsPageDrawer(),
      body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'] as Widget,

      bottomNavigationBar: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 90,
              child: Stack(
                clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                children: [
                  CustomPaint(
                    size: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 90),
                    painter: BNBCustomPainter(),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    heightFactor: 0.7,
                    child: FloatingActionButton(
                      backgroundColor:
                          Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark
                              ? blueDMColor
                              : blueLMColor,
                      child: FaIcon(
                          themeState.darkTheme
                              ? FontAwesomeIcons.houseChimney
                              : FontAwesomeIcons.houseChimney,
                          color: _onTap ? Colors.white : Colors.white),
                      elevation: 0.1,
                      onPressed: () => setState(() {
                        _selectedPageIndex = 2;
                      }),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: 111,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(150, 0, 0, 0),
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              color: Theme.of(context).brightness ==
                                      Brightness.dark
                                  ? orangeDMColor
                                  : orangeLMColor,
                            ),
                            child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.bar_chart, color: Colors.white),
                              onPressed: () => _selectPage(0),
                              tooltip: 'Abilities',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            color:
                                Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark
                                    ? greenDMColor
                                    : greenLMColor,
                          ),
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.school, color: Colors.white),
                            onPressed: () => _selectPage(1),
                            tooltip: 'Education',
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.20,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            color:
                                Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark
                                    ? purpleDMColor
                                    : purpleLMColor,
                          ),
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.work, color: Colors.white),
                            onPressed: () => _selectPage(3),
                            tooltip: 'Employments',
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 150, 0),
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              color: Theme.of(context).brightness ==
                                      Brightness.dark
                                  ? magentaDMColor
                                  : magentaLMColor,
                            ),
                            child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white),
                              onPressed: () => _selectPage(4),
                              tooltip: 'About',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),

      floatingActionButtonLocation:
          FloatingActionButtonLocation.miniCenterDocked,
    );
  }
}

class BNBCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = new Paint()
      ..color = Colors.green
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 30); // Start
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.20, 0, size.width * 0.40, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.45, 0, size.width * 0.45, 20);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width * 0.55, 20),
        radius: Radius.circular(20.0), clockwise: false);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.55, 0, size.width * 0.65, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.80, 0, size.width, 30);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, 30);
    canvas.drawShadow(path, Colors.black, 5, true);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2D1I.png) screen shot of how new code should be, but won't call pages

chatGPT4 for 5 hrs of fails in every way until I ripped my eyes out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code seems ok, except for the optimisations needed. You are not able to see the change of page as for the usage of `Stack` in the `bottomNavigationBar`. The `Stack` here covers the entire viewport and the sub pages in the body goes behind.

Wrap the `Stack` with a `SizedBox` as below:

```
SizedBox(
        height: 100,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
```

This will help you to see the page contents.

I suggest some optimisation as below:

```
  late List<Map<String, Widget>> _pages;
```

For the body:

```
 body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page']!,
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Here is build method code after removing some variables:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final themeState = Provider.of<DarkThemeProvider>(context);
    print('rebuild with $_selectedPageIndex');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 40,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        elevation: 3.0,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page']!,
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: SizedBox(
        height: 100,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 90,
                child: Stack(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                  children: [
                    CustomPaint(
                      size: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 90),
                      painter: BNBCustomPainter(),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      heightFactor: 0.7,
                      child: FloatingActionButton(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                        child: Icon(Icons.house,
                            color: _onTap ? Colors.white : Colors.white),
                        elevation: 0.1,
                        onPressed: () => setState(() {
                          _selectedPageIndex = 2;
                        }),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      //width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      height: 111,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 0, 0, 0),
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                color: Colors.orange,
                              ),
                              child: IconButton(
                                icon:
                                    Icon(Icons.bar_chart, color: Colors.white),
                                onPressed: () => _selectPage(0),
                                tooltip: 'Abilities',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              color: Colors.indigo,
                            ),
                            child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.school, color: Colors.white),
                              onPressed: () => _selectPage(1),
                              tooltip: 'Education',
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.20,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              color: Colors.purple,
                            ),
                            child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.work, color: Colors.white),
                              onPressed: () => _selectPage(3),
                              tooltip: 'Employments',
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 50, 0),
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                              child: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white),
                                onPressed: () => _selectPage(4),
                                tooltip: 'About',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation:
          FloatingActionButtonLocation.miniCenterDocked,
    );
  }
}
```

And the _pages List I used to test

```
_pages = [
      {
        'page': Container(
          color: Colors.orange,
          child: Text('Page 1'),
        ),
      },
      {
        'page': Container(
          color: Colors.indigo,
          child: Text('Page 2'),
        ),
      },
      {
        'page': Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Text('Page 3'),
        ),
      },
      {
        'page': Container(
          color: Colors.purple,
          child: Text(
            'Page 4',
          ),
        ),
      },
      {
        'page': Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Text('Page 5'),
        ),
      },
    ];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That SizedBox did the trick for the Stack. I don't have enough clout in StackOverflow to give it a checkmark in the answer spot, so feel free to check it yourself and give yourself a pat on the back for me. Thanks again!!!

Comment: I also wrapped that in a LayoutBuilder to keep it responsive to my code.

Comment: Thanks again. It took my checkmark (I guess marked useful?) after I commented my answer. if the upvote is the up and down arrows I get this...
"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."
Any other kooDoes I can give let me know. Blessings to ya!